# Fundamental theorem of Calculus failure cause

Tags: calculus

I know the examples don’t of trying it with improper integrals don’t give sensible answers, and why they don’t make sense, *but what makes them not work?* What is it in the geometric, word/thought experiment, graphical, or anything else intuition that comes from our definition of integrals that makes us have to, say, split it at a singularity? Surely numerical integration only gives you one result, but splitting it like this gives you two. Is there something that’s leads us to knowing that it can fail without having to try examples? Just some context. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Can you give a more specific problem?

Comment: @MathLover I had -1 to 1 of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ on my mind but I don’t really care about it, although I guess that’s an example if you want one. Computation thus far hasn’t helped me understand in depth so I doubt some specific evaluation will help.

Comment: This question is looking for something specific, but it’s not a *particular* problem. I can’t connect having to solve improper integrals differently to the foundational concepts of derivatives and integrals. That is, when I do calc it usually feels like what I’m writing is a just a representation of something grounded and intuitive happening in my head but this is not the case here.

Comment: I think integrals are just the way they are, so if there is some things that doesn’t work, you can just check if the steps proving this doesn’t work for certain numbers-I think, but I’m not that sure.

Comment: If the hypotheses of the theorem aren't satisfied, you can hardly expect the theorem to hold.

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern is, but it sounds like you are overlooking the fact that ordinary Riemann definite integrals are **defined** only over closed and bounded intervals for functions that are bounded on that interval. If you want to consider the idea of integration on other sets, such as an open finite-length interval or an interval of infinite length or a function that is not bounded, then you have to provide a definition for such an integral before proceeding. It's like asking about the word 'ko*)^bc', which isn't in the form of a word because non-alphabetic symbols are used.

Comment: @saulspatz I agree but why are these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the fundamental theorem this way.  If you periodically measure the speed at which the distance of an object from given point is changing, you can estimate the distance of the object from that point.  That is, $f(t)-f(0)\approx \sum\triangle x_n f'(x_n)$  The (second) fundamental theorem of calculus says that this approximation becomes an equality in the limit.

Think of a ship in the days of sail, before there were good star charts.  They figured out approximately where they were, in part, by measuring their speed though the water every so often ("casting the log.")  But now suppose the Sea God picks the ship up and puts it down somewhere else instantaneously, so that the ship's velocity is undefined.  Measuring is pointless now.

I hope this is intuitive enough.